# keypad doesn't work + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am making a numeric keypad and I want to use it inside jQuery Form Wizard and Validation.
every thing is working but not keypad :(
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BngRv/)

```
$(function () {
  var keypad = $('#keypad');
  keypad.hide();

  $('input[type="text"]:not(#keypad)').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).after(keypad);
    keypad.show();
  });
});

function addIt(cKey) {
  var id = $('#keypad').prev().attr('id');
  d = document.getElementById(id);
  d.value = (cKey.value == 'delete') 
    ? d.value.slice(0, -1) 
    : ((cKey.value == 'clear') ? "" : d.value + cKey.value);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BngRv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the function `addIt` to the HTML section in fiddle.

```
<script>
    function addIt(cKey) {
        var id = $('#keypad').prev().attr('id');
        d = document.getElementById(id);
        d.value = (cKey.value == 'delete') ? d.value.slice(0, -1) : ((cKey.value == 'clear') ? "" : d.value + cKey.value);
    }
</script>
```

**Fixed Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/BngRv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your loading block and remove the onClicks in each button input:

```
$(function(){
    //rest of code before it here
    $('.keypad').click(function(){
        addIt($(this).val());
    });
});
```